# Программа для рисования дизайна сайта

Tags: веб-дизайн, поиск-программ

Как рисуют вот такие картинки дизайнов сайта? Видел у ютуба до полной прогрузки DOM или загрузки js примерно такой же как это назвать структурно-схематический дизайн. Поправьте,если неправильно назвал термин.

[image: Вот]

Comment: В Adobe Illustrator можно подобное рисовать. Пробежитесь по продуктам Adobe, там куча инструментов

Comment: А где можно туториалы об этом посмотреть или что-то в этом роде?

Comment: Вы на оф сайт зайдите, там куча всего есть, для начала. Плюс по торрентам много всего есть

Comment: Зашел,посмотрел-но такого не нашел. Что-то вы не то советуете

Comment: Или вы не так ищете. Вопрос нужно закрыть, так как не относится к программированию. Вам вероятно нужно на какие-либо ресурсы дизайнеров.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не относится к программированию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pixate. Как раз то,что мне нужно

Comment: Всё, закрылись: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOgFQ.png